# Django: combine items from two queries (two different Models) together

Tags: mysql, sql, django, postgresql

I'm building an event platform with Django with some events *public* and some *invite*-only. Here's how it basically works:

- Every event is based on the **Event** model.
- Private events are only viewable by invited guests: this is achieved
  through an **Invite** model referencing both the event and the guest.
- Users can inform whether they will be attending an event or not
  through an **Answer** model that stores the associated event, user
  and the answer.
- The **Answer** and **Invite** models are totally independent from each other, that way I am able to use the **Answer** model for both public and private events.

---

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

For each event where I'm invited, display the invitation (event.creator invited you to event.name) and, if it exists, my associated answer, else display a form to answer.

So I think what I'm trying to do is getting all events where I'm invited (I have no problem with that) and joining that to my answer (where user=me). The problem is that the answer might not even exist yet --if I haven't answered.

Ideally, I would have all of that in one single query so that I could do something like this in the templates: invited_event.answer and display the answer if it exists.

### EDIT:

**So I think what I need ultimately is to mix two queries: one that gets all the events where I'm invited (1) and an other that grabs all answers for those events (2).**

(1)

```
latest_events_invited = Event.objects.filter(invite__user_invited=request.user)
```

(2)

```
answers_events_invited = Answer.objects.filter(user_answering=request.user, event__in=latest_events_invited)
```

Something like: for each event in latest_events_invited, append corresponding answer from answers_events_invited.

**Any ideas?**

---

**Code:**

My template (index.html):

```
<h3>Invites</h3>
{% if latest_invites_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for event in latest_events_invited %}
        <li>
            {{ event.creator }} invited you to {{ event }}<br/ >

            <!--IDEALLY:-->
            {% if event.answer %}
                    You answered: {{ answer.answer }}
            {% else %}
                <form action="{% url 'events:answer_event' invite.event.id %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    Answer:
                    <select name="answer">
                        <option value="1" >Attending</option>
                        <option value="2" >Not attending</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Answer">
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No invites.</p>
{% endif %}
```

The view (views.py)

```
def index(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        latest_events_invited = Event.objects.filter(invite__user_invited=request.user)
        latest_answers_list = Answer.objects.filter(user_answering=request.user, event__in=latest_events_invited)
        
        #do something with those to get: "latest_events_invited_with_answers"

        context = {'latest_events_invited':latest_events_invited, 'latest_answers_list':latest_answers_list}

    else:
        [...]

return render(request, 'events/index.html', context)
```

And the models.

**Event**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    PRIVACY_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Public'),
        (1, 'Invite only'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    [...]
    privacy = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=1, choices=PRIVACY_CHOICES, default=0)
    invited = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Invite', related_name='events_invited', blank=True)
    answers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Answer', related_name='events_answered', blank=True)
```

**Invite**

```
class Invite(models.Model):

    user_invited = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user_invited", "event"),)
```

**Answer**

```
class Answer(models.Model):

    ANSWER_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Attending'),
        (2, 'Not attending'),
    )

    user_answering = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    answer = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(max_length=1, choices=ANSWER_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user_answering", "event"),)
```

Hopefully someone here can help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. I don't know if this is the optimal solution but it works for now.
In the end, it is only 2 queries, which I combine with for loops.

Here's the code: (views.py)

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        latest_events_invited = Event.objects.filter(invite__user_invited=request.user)
        latest_answers_for_events = Answer.objects.filter(user_answering=request.user, event__in=latest_events_invited)

        for event in latest_events_invited:
            for answer in latest_answers_for_events:
                if answer.event.id == event.id:
                    event.answer = answer.answer
                else:
                    event.answer = ''

    context = {'latest_events_invited': latest_events_invited,}

    return render(request, 'events/index.html', context)
```

I can then access the answer directly in the template (index.html) like so:

```
{{ event.answer }}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to automatically add an Answer whenever someone is invited, with a default of No. Use the post_save signal of Invite or overwrite the save method so you don't have to create an associated Answer each time.

Another option, probably better, is to do the logic in the view rather than in the template. Check if an answer exists; if it does, pass a list of answers to the template; if not, pass an empty list.

EDIT: Or, better yet:

In the view:

```
try:
  user_answer = Answer.objects.filter(user_answering = request.user).filter(event=event)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
  answer = None
```

EDIT2: Or how about:

```
Answer.objects.filter(user_answering = request.user).filter(event__in=Event.objects.filter(user__in = event.invited))
```

Comment: One of the reasons of having independent Answer and Invite models was to avoid having empty fields in the db.
As for the logic in the view, that's the solution that i'm looking for. What you suggest adds one query per event, though, right?   Couldn't it be possible to join the whole answer table at once with blanks for unexisting rows?

Comment: See my updated response. I think I found a more elegant solution. Nonetheless, I don't think it's possible, with your model setup, to not do a query per event, unless you're ok with empty fields. Maybe in raw SQL, which I'm not so great with, but definitely not in Django.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wish it were that easy but I don't think that'll work. See, I don't have just one event, I'm getting a **list** of all events where I'm invited. Otherwise, I'm open to changing my model setup if you can think of one that makes more sense.

Comment: So iterate over all the events? Do you expect there to be a lot? If so, how about: Answer.objects.filter(user_answering = request.user).filter(event__in=Event.objects.filter(user__in = event.invited))? That's in my response too now, in case the formatting here is hard to read.

Comment: The problem with that is that if the user hasn't answered yet, there will be no result even though there might be an invite. I think the solution would be something along the lines of: getting all events where I'm invited (query #1), getting all my answers for those events (query #2) and then (step 3) mixing those two queries somehow but that's the part that I can't figure out.